# How to better parse the same table twice with Anorm?

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

Suppose I have the following two classes:

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String)

case class Message(id: Long, body: String, to: User, from: User)
```

The `RowParser`s might look something like this:

```
val parser: RowParser[User] = {
    get[Long]("users.id") ~ get[String]("users.name") map {
        case id~name => User(id, name)
    }
}

val parser: RowParser[Message] = {
    get[Long]("messages.id") ~ 
    get[String]("messages.name") ~
    User.parser ~
    User.parser map {
        case id~body~to~from => Message(id, body, to, from)
    }
}
```

Except that this won't work, because when joining the `users` table twice, Anorm will only parse the first joined columns (twice), so that `to` and `from` will be the same.

This can be overcome using column aliases in the `User` parser:

```
def parser(alias: String): RowParser[User] = {
    getAliased[Long](alias + "_id") ~ getAliased[String](alias + "_name") map {
        case id~name => User(id, name)
    }
}
```

Then using different aliases for each `User` in the `Message` parser:

```
val parser: RowParser[Message] = {
    get[Long]("messages.id") ~ 
    get[String]("messages.name") ~
    User.parser("to") ~
    User.parser("from") map {
        case id~body~to~from => Message(id, body, to, from)
    }
}
```

This is okay for simple scenarios, but what if `User` is more complicated and has an `Address` with a `State` and `Country`, etc? That would require aliasing multiple tables and parsers, which gets quite messy.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? That is, I'm looking to select all of the relevant data in one query, and parse it using parser combinators, without a massive column aliasing scheme.

Comment: Don't think there is other way than aliasing, as join can fetch different 'entities' from a table used several time in a query, each need to be made distinct with aliases.

Comment: You don't really need your method, it's possibly more compact just to write: `getAliased[String]("to_name") ~` etc, directly in the parser?

Comment: @wwkudu But then I would need two parsers, one with `to_name` and one with `from_name`, etc. The example is also fairly simplified, the `User` parser would really have many more fields, and nested parsers.

Comment: Ah, point taken. My case was only a single attribute. I think your solution is close to optimal - you are parameterising the alias as it were. (BTW, should users.id and users.name not be message.id and message body?)

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. Thanks. The aliasing solution works okay, but it can get rather messy with nesting. It also makes queries look extremely ugly.

Comment: How is the query more ugly, do you want to post an example? (I am going to be facing your situation soon, so interested!). Your `def parser` basically just replaces `val parser` for the user injecting the alias, so seems pretty good to me.

Comment: Instead of having `u1.*, u2.*`, I have to enumerate all of the aliases like: `u1.id as to_id, u1.name as to_name, u2.id as from_name, u2.name as from_name`... which gets unwieldy when more columns are needed. And up until this point I've avoided nesting anything within `User` to keep the query from exploding in size.

Comment: Rather than `.*`, I already use a variable `sqlSelectorFields`, so I think I'm going to parameterise this to `sqlSelectorFields(alias)`.