# In Anorm is it possible to apply multiple ColumnAliaser to the same query

Tags: scala, anorm

The scenario is similar to the question at [How to better parse the same table twice with Anorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652731/how-to-better-parse-the-same-table-twice-with-anorm) however the described solutions on that question can no longer be used.

On the scenario where a Message has 2 users I need to parse the from_user and to_user with SQL joins.

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String)

case class Message(id: Long, body: String, to: User, from: User)

def userParser(alias: String): RowParser[User] = {
    get[Long](alias + "_id") ~ get[String](alias + "_name") map {
        case id~name => User(id, name)
    }
}

val parser: RowParser[Message] = {
    userParser("from_user") ~
    userParser("to_user") ~
    get[Long]("messages.id") ~ 
    get[String]("messages.name") map {
        case from~to~id~body => Message(id, body, to, from)
    }
}

// More alias here possible ?
val aliaser: ColumnAliaser = ColumnAliaser.withPattern((0 to 2).toSet, "from_user.")

SQL"""
SELECT from_user.* , to_user.*, message.* FROM MESSAGE
JOIN USER from_user on from_user.id = message_from_user_id
JOIN USER to_user on to_user.id = message.to_user
"""
.asTry(parser, aliaser)
```

Comment: Please precise the question: I guess the question is not whether a `ColumnAliaser` instance can be reused (as it obviously can as immutable), but is it possible to apply multiple `ColumnAliaser` to the same query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm right thinking you want to apply multiple `ColumnAliaser` with different aliasing policies to the same query, it's important to understand that `ColumnAliaser` is "just" a [specific implementation of `Function[(Int, ColumnName), Option[String]]`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#anorm.ColumnAliaser), so it can be defined/composed as any [`Function`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1), and is simplified by the factory functions in its [companion object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#anorm.ColumnAliaser$).

```
import anorm.{ ColumnAliaser, ColumnName }

val aliaser = new ColumnAliaser {
  def as1 = ColumnAliaser.withPattern((0 to 2).toSet, "from_user.")
  def as2 = ColumnAliaser.withPattern((2 to 4).toSet, "to_user.")

  def apply(column: (Int, ColumnName)): Option[String] =
    as1(column).orElse(as2(column))
}
```